# How to locate the dynamic web elements using webdriver

Tags: selenium

The Web page is written using aspx pages. Where are there are no fixed rows and elements. Which gets changed dynamically.

Please review the attached code and let me know how to form CSS Selector path/Xpath to  locate the button "showAirlineCreateButton", whose position changes dynamically.

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="client_name col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8">
   <h4 class="ng-binding">TEST </h4>
     </div>

                    <!-- ngRepeat: scheduleBasicDetail in Airline_item.scheduleBasicDetailList --><div ng-repeat="scheduleBasicDetail in Airline_item.scheduleBasicDetailList" class="ng-scope">
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8" style="height:86px;">
                        <!-- ngIf: scheduleBasicDetail.Client_ID!=0 --><div class="tri_widget widget md-whiteframe-z2 ng-scope ng-isolate-scope flex layout-column" ng-class="::{'widget-overlay-title': vm.overlayTitle}" flex="" layout="column" ng-if="scheduleBasicDetail.Client_ID!=0" title-position="top" ng-click="redirect(scheduleBasicDetail.Schedule_ID,scheduleBasicDetail.Client_ID)" title="" role="button" tabindex="0"><!-- ngIf: ::(vm.title || vm.subtitle) --><div class="widget-content layout-column layout-align-start-stretch flex-order-2" layout="column" layout-align="" ng-class="{'layout-padding': vm.contentPadding}" ng-transclude="" flex-order="2">
                            <div layout="row" layout-wrap="" class="layout-wrap ng-scope layout-row">
                                <div flex="10" class="flex-10">
                                    <img class="TESTListFirstTableTdImage" ng-src="http://10.255.109.100/TESTService/Services/../Repository/TEST/TEST/Logo.png" src="http://10.255.109.100/TESTService/Services/../Repository/TEST/TEST/Logo.png">
                                </div>
                                <div flex="80" class="Small_Padding_Left flex-80">
                                <div layout="row" class="layout-row">
                                  
                                     <div flex="33" id="title" class="ng-binding flex-33">HX-JAN17-01</div>
                                    <div flex="33" class="AirLineScheduleSystemName ng-binding flex-33">PAC eFX / PAC eX2 / Thales i5000</div>
                                    <div flex="33" class="flex-33"></div>
                                </div>
                                    <div layout="row" class="layout-row">
                                    <div flex="33" class="flex-33"><span class="TESTScheduleMonth ng-binding">January</span> <br>
                                    <span class="TESTScheduleYear ng-binding">2017</span>   
                                    </div>
                                    <div flex="66" class="flex-66"><span class="AirLineScheduleAssets ng-binding">0 Assets</span><br>
                                          <span class="TESTScheduleAssets ng-binding">MOVIES / I-MOVIES / TV / OTHERS</span>   
                                    </div>
                                   
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div flex="10" class="flex-10">
                                        <img ng-src="http://10.255.109.100/TESTService/Services/../Repository/ScheduleStatus/Locked.png" ng-altsrc="../../Images/Common/NoImage.png" onerror="this.src = $(this).attr('altSrc')" src="http://10.255.109.100/TESTService/Services/../Repository/ScheduleStatus/Locked.png">
                                </div>
                                </div>

                         </div><div class="widget-loading ng-hide layout-fill layout-align-center-center layout-row" ng-show="vm.loading" layout="" layout-fill="" layout-align="center center" aria-hidden="true"><div class="widget-loading-inner ng-hide" ng-show="vm.loading" aria-hidden="true"><md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" role="progressbar" class="ng-isolate-scope" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"><path fill="none" transform="rotate(49.63717240968655 25, 25)" d="M23.589212129501437,47.455727055351694A22.5,22.5 0 0,0 28.277287287607944,47.2600401624634" style="stroke-width: 5px;"></path></svg></md-progress-circular></div></div></div><!-- end ngIf: scheduleBasicDetail.Client_ID!=0 -->
                        <!-- ngIf: scheduleBasicDetail.Client_ID==0 -->                                 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2 dropdown-parent-div">
                            <div class="dropdown">
                            <i class="dropbtn fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <div class="dropdown-content" style="margin-top:22px">
                                    <strong><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Export as XLS Of MetaData" ng-click="download(scheduleBasicDetail.Schedule_ID)"> <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o icon-4x dropdown-excel-button" aria-hidden="true">  </i></a></strong>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dropdown-content" style="margin-top:22px">
                                    <strong><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Export as XLS Of Translation" ng-click="download_Translation(scheduleBasicDetail.Schedule_ID)"> <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o icon-4x dropdown-excel-button" aria-hidden="true">  </i></a></strong>
                                </div>                                
                             </div>                                                  
                         </div>
                     </div><!-- end ngRepeat: scheduleBasicDetail in TEST_item.scheduleBasicDetailList --><div ng-repeat="scheduleBasicDetail in TEST_item.scheduleBasicDetailList" class="ng-scope">
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8" style="height:86px;">
                        <!-- ngIf: scheduleBasicDetail.Client_ID!=0 --><div class="tri_widget widget md-whiteframe-z2 ng-scope ng-isolate-scope flex layout-column" ng-class="::{'widget-overlay-title': vm.overlayTitle}" flex="" layout="column" ng-if="scheduleBasicDetail.Client_ID!=0" title-position="top" ng-click="redirect(scheduleBasicDetail.Schedule_ID,scheduleBasicDetail.Client_ID)" title="" role="button" tabindex="0"><!-- ngIf: ::(vm.title || vm.subtitle) --><div class="widget-content layout-column layout-align-start-stretch flex-order-2" layout="column" layout-align="" ng-class="{'layout-padding': vm.contentPadding}" ng-transclude="" flex-order="2">
                            <div layout="row" layout-wrap="" class="layout-wrap ng-scope layout-row">
                                <div flex="10" class="flex-10">
                                    <img class="AirlineScheduleListFirstTableTdImage" ng-src="http://10.255.109.100/TESTService/Services/../Repository/Airline/TEST/Logo.png" src="http://10.255.109.100/TESTService/Services/../Repository/Airline/TEST/Logo.png">
                                </div>
                                <div flex="80" class="Small_Padding_Left flex-80">
                                <div layout="row" class="layout-row">
                                  
                                     <div flex="33" id="title" class="ng-binding flex-33">HX-DEC16-01</div>
                                    <div flex="33" class="AirLineScheduleSystemName ng-binding flex-33">PAC eFX / PAC eX2 / Thales i5000</div>
                                    <div flex="33" class="flex-33"></div>
                                </div>
                                    <div layout="row" class="layout-row">
                                    <div flex="33" class="flex-33"><span class="TESTScheduleMonth ng-binding">December</span> <br>
                                    <span class="AirLineScheduleYear ng-binding">2016</span>   
                                    </div>
                                    <div flex="66" class="flex-66"><span class="AirLineScheduleAssets ng-binding">29 Assets</span><br>
                                          <span class="TESTScheduleAssets ng-binding">MOVIES / I-MOVIES / TV / OTHERS</span>   
                                    </div>
                                   
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div flex="10" class="flex-10">
                                        <img ng-src="http://10.255.109.100/DASHService/Services/../Repository/ScheduleStatus/Locked.png" ng-altsrc="../../Images/Common/NoImage.png" onerror="this.src = $(this).attr('altSrc')" src="http://10.255.109.100/DASHService/Services/../Repository/ScheduleStatus/Locked.png">
                                </div>
                                </div>

                         </div><div class="widget-loading ng-hide layout-fill layout-align-center-center layout-row" ng-show="vm.loading" layout="" layout-fill="" layout-align="center center" aria-hidden="true"><div class="widget-loading-inner ng-hide" ng-show="vm.loading" aria-hidden="true"><md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" role="progressbar" class="ng-isolate-scope" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"><path fill="none" transform="rotate(49.63717240968655 25, 25)" d="M23.589212129501437,47.455727055351694A22.5,22.5 0 0,0 28.276617692292554,47.26013873493504" style="stroke-width: 5px;"></path></svg></md-progress-circular></div></div></div><!-- end ngIf: scheduleBasicDetail.Client_ID!=0 -->
                        <!-- ngIf: scheduleBasicDetail.Client_ID==0 -->                                 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2 dropdown-parent-div">
                            <div class="dropdown">
                            <i class="dropbtn fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <div class="dropdown-content" style="margin-top:22px">
                                    <strong><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Export as XLS Of MetaData" ng-click="download(scheduleBasicDetail.Schedule_ID)"> <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o icon-4x dropdown-excel-button" aria-hidden="true">  </i></a></strong>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dropdown-content" style="margin-top:22px">
                                    <strong><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Export as XLS Of Translation" ng-click="download_Translation(scheduleBasicDetail.Schedule_ID)"> <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o icon-4x dropdown-excel-button" aria-hidden="true">  </i></a></strong>
                                </div>                                
                             </div>                                                  
                         </div>
                     </div><!-- end ngRepeat: scheduleBasicDetail in Airline_item.scheduleBasicDetailList --><div ng-repeat="scheduleBasicDetail in Airline_item.scheduleBasicDetailList" class="ng-scope">
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8" style="height:86px;">
                        <!-- ngIf: scheduleBasicDetail.Client_ID!=0 --><div class="tri_widget widget md-whiteframe-z2 ng-scope ng-isolate-scope flex layout-column" ng-class="::{'widget-overlay-title': vm.overlayTitle}" flex="" layout="column" ng-if="scheduleBasicDetail.Client_ID!=0" title-position="top" ng-click="redirect(scheduleBasicDetail.Schedule_ID,scheduleBasicDetail.Client_ID)" title="" role="button" tabindex="0"><!-- ngIf: ::(vm.title || vm.subtitle) --><div class="widget-content layout-column layout-align-start-stretch flex-order-2" layout="column" layout-align="" ng-class="{'layout-padding': vm.contentPadding}" ng-transclude="" flex-order="2">
                            <div layout="row" layout-wrap="" class="layout-wrap ng-scope layout-row">
                                <div flex="10" class="flex-10">
                                    <img class="AirlineScheduleListFirstTableTdImage" ng-src="http://10.255.109.100/DASHService/Services/../Repository/Airline/Hong_Kong_Airlines/Logo.png" src="http://10.255.109.100/DASHService/Services/../Repository/Airline/Hong_Kong_Airlines/Logo.png">
                                </div>
                                <div flex="80" class="Small_Padding_Left flex-80">
                                <div layout="row" class="layout-row">
                                  
                                     <div flex="33" id="title" class="ng-binding flex-33">HX-SEP16-01</div>
                                    <div flex="33" class="AirLineScheduleSystemName ng-binding flex-33">PAC eFX / PAC eX2 / Thales i5000</div>
                                    <div flex="33" class="flex-33"></div>
                                </div>
                                    <div layout="row" class="layout-row">
                                    <div flex="33" class="flex-33"><span class="AirLineScheduleMonth ng-binding">September</span> <br>
                                    <span class="AirLineScheduleYear ng-binding">2016</span>   
                                    </div>
                                    <div flex="66" class="flex-66"><span class="AirLineScheduleAssets ng-binding">50 Assets</span><br>
                                          <span class="AirLineScheduleAssets ng-binding">MOVIES / I-MOVIES / TV / OTHERS</span>   
                                    </div>
                                   
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div flex="10" class="flex-10">
                                        <img ng-src="http://10.255.109.100/DASHService/Services/../Repository/ScheduleStatus/Locked.png" ng-altsrc="../../Images/Common/NoImage.png" onerror="this.src = $(this).attr('altSrc')" src="http://10.255.109.100/DASHService/Services/../Repository/ScheduleStatus/Locked.png">
                                </div>
                                </div>

                         </div><div class="widget-loading ng-hide layout-fill layout-align-center-center layout-row" ng-show="vm.loading" layout="" layout-fill="" layout-align="center center" aria-hidden="true"><div class="widget-loading-inner ng-hide" ng-show="vm.loading" aria-hidden="true"><md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" role="progressbar" class="ng-isolate-scope" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"><path fill="none" transform="rotate(49.63717240968655 25, 25)" d="M23.589212129501437,47.455727055351694A22.5,22.5 0 0,0 28.275447404006268,47.260310966012774" style="stroke-width: 5px;"></path></svg></md-progress-circular></div></div></div><!-- end ngIf: scheduleBasicDetail.Client_ID!=0 -->
                        <!-- ngIf: scheduleBasicDetail.Client_ID==0 -->                                 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2 dropdown-parent-div">
                            <div class="dropdown">
                            <i class="dropbtn fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <div class="dropdown-content" style="margin-top:22px">
                                    <strong><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Export as XLS Of MetaData" ng-click="download(scheduleBasicDetail.Schedule_ID)"> <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o icon-4x dropdown-excel-button" aria-hidden="true">  </i></a></strong>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dropdown-content" style="margin-top:22px">
                                    <strong><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Export as XLS Of Translation" ng-click="download_Translation(scheduleBasicDetail.Schedule_ID)"> <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o icon-4x dropdown-excel-button" aria-hidden="true">  </i></a></strong>
                                </div>                                
                             </div>                                                  
                         </div>
                     </div><!-- end ngRepeat: scheduleBasicDetail in Airline_item.scheduleBasicDetailList --> 
                           
                    
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2  div_add_btn">  
                        <!-- ngIf: showAirlineCreateButton --><div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-6 text-center add_btn_schedule ng-scope" ng-click="Show_AirName(Airline_item.Client_ID,Airline_item.ClientName,Airline_item.scheduleBasicDetailList[0].Schedule_ID)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-ng-if="showAirlineCreateButton" role="button" tabindex="0">
                            <span class="fa fa-plus" aria-label="Create a Schedule">
                                
 </span>
 /div><!-- end ngIf: showAirlineCreateButton -->
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `XPath` that should work no matter where element located:

`//div[@data-ng-if="showAirlineCreateButton"]`

Comment: Hi Anderson, Thank you very much for your answer. It works, i am able to click on Show Airline button.

Comment: Similarly, no. of rows in the colum changes at run time. How to find a particular row( with image: draft, in progress and   Locked) and navigate to it.

Comment: You , mean table row? `<tr>`? Is it new issue? Provide `HTML` for same

Comment: It is not a new issue. It is in the existing code, which sent earlier           <div layout="row" layout-wrap="" class="layout-wrap ng-scope layout-row"><img class="TESTScheduleListFirstTableTdImage" ng-src="http://10.255.109.100/TESTService/Services/../Repository/Airline/KLM/Logo.png" </div>
 <div flex="80" class="Small_Padding_Left flex-80">
<div layout="row" class="layout-row">
<div flex="33" id="title" class="ng-binding flex-33">TestSchedule3</div>
<div flex="33" class="TESTSystemName ng-binding flex-33">PACeX2QT / PAC3000i / PACeX2</div>
<div flex="33" class="flex-33"></div>
</div>